# 「画像のプリロード」処理を実装しても、画像表示処理自体が速くなるわけではない？

Tags: javascript

**「画像のプリロード」処理を実装しても、画像表示処理自体は速くならないのでしょうか？**
・画像を全部読込終了後に、実行したい処理を指定できるようになるだけですか？
・例えば1000枚の画像を表示する場合、1枚目の画像を表示する時間は、「画像のプリロード」処理を実装しようがしまいが変わらない、ということでしょうか？
・むしろ、全部の画像読込を待つので、遅くなることもあり得る？？？

Comment: 質問趣旨がいまひとつ読み取れないのですが、"速く"とはどこ(いつ)を基点としていて、何に対して(比較対象)でしょうか？プリロード処理は文字通り「事前のデータ取得」でしかありません。

Comment: 基点はユーザがページへアクセスした時点です。比較対象は「プリロード処理」を実装している場合と、実装していない場合です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「画像のプリロード」処理を実装しても、画像表示処理自体は速くならないのでしょうか？

画像のプリロードで実現されるのは転送時間の省略なので、「画像の表示処理」がデータとして受信が完了しているものを表示するためにかかる時間ということでしたら速くなりません。

> ・画像を全部読込終了後に、実行したい処理を指定できるようになるだけですか？

アプリケーションの実装次第です。「画像をすべて読み込む、終わったら次の処理」というコードを書けばそうなりますし、リクエストの送信タイミングやレスポンスの非同期処理を考慮したコードを書けば、他の処理と「プリロード」の処理順をコントロールできます

> ・例えば1000枚の画像を表示する場合、1枚目の画像を表示する時間は、「画像のプリロード」処理を実装しようがしまいが変わらない、ということでしょうか？
>   ・むしろ、全部の画像読込を待つので、遅くなることもあり得る？？？

「1枚目」がページ遷移のタイミングで必ず表示されるような画像なのであれば、それに「プリロード」処理を使うのは無駄なので遅くなるでしょう。全部の転送を待つかどうかは上に書いたとおり実装次第です。